# Why do I have a mobile icon beside my name on Facebook chat?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

So I was away for a while on Facebook and my friend noticed that I was getting a Mobile Icon when he looked at me in his chat list. It seems like whenever I am offline it says that beside my friend's chat. It says `Last active h ago`.

I don't use Facebook on mobile. I have logged into another friend's phone once but I recalled correctly that I logged out and he even reset his phone apps once.

I checked my friend and whenever he was offline, it would show nothing. It didn't matter how long he was offline. Mine showed an icon and time ago active but his doesn't.

Why does it show nothing beside his name? Why doesn't it happen for me? Shouldn't it show nothing beside my chat when I'm offline?

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, kill all your (other) sessions from your account activity panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Facebook has some mobile deviceId against your name as you logged in from mobile once. Though you have logged out from that mobile device, the data has not cleared yet.

In security settings, you can check active session and here you can end the session causing this problem.

Comment: Thanks it actually works! So what I did was kill the "Android Session"